# Multiple intents won't run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two intents that I am trying to run using Shortcuts app.

This is the tests I have ran in `IntentHandler`:

This works:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        
        guard intent is CarIDIntent else {
            return .none
         }
         return AccessTokenIntentHandler()
     }
 }
```

This works:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        
        guard intent is AccessTokenIntent else {
            return .none
        }
        return AccessTokenIntentHandler()
     }
 }
```

This does not work:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        
        guard intent is AccessTokenIntent else {
            return .none
        }
        
        guard intent is CarIDIntent else {
            return .none
        }
        
        return AccessTokenIntentHandler()
     }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Both of them are added to the `Intents.intentdefinition` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a switch case, but since you haven't given any information about what the error tells you it's hard to find a exact solution. Try this:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        switch intent {
        case is AccessTokenIntent:
            print("Access Token")
        case is CarIDIntent:
            print("Car ID")
        default:
            return .none
        }
        return AccessTokenIntentHandler()
     }
 }
```